# clone -> change ids -> add content -> display -> append to parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i have the following setup

```
<div class="article-content">
    <div class='editors' id="mine">
        <h2>My Text</h2>
        <textarea name="my_text" id="my_text" class="my_test"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class='editors' id="termsy_master" style="display:none;">
        <h2>title</h2>
        <textarea name="" id="" class="sm">text</textarea>
        <textarea name="" id="" class="di">text</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

im trying to

- clone "termsy_master"
- change the id to "his"
- change the h2 title to "new title"
- textarea sm id to "sm_new_id"
- textarea di id to "di_new_id"
- remove display none so it'll be visible
- and append it to article-content

i have the following already done, but im not sure how to proceed

```
$('.article-content').append($("#termsy_master").clone());
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$tmc = $("#termsy_master").clone().attr('id', 'his').show();
$("h2", $tmc).text('new title');
$(".sm", $tmc).attr('id', 'sm_new_id');
$(".di", $tmc).attr('id', 'di_new_id');
$tmc.appendTo(".article-content");
```

There are lots of ways  you could do it of course, but this seems to be more or less the simplest to me.  Don't overthink!

Answer (score 3):

Here is one possible solution:

```
var block = $("#termsy_master"​).clone();
block.children("h2").text("new title");
block.children(".sm").attr("id", "sm_new_id");
block.children(".di").attr("id", "di_new_id");
block.attr("id", "his").show().appendTo(".article-content");​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8pxPC/

---

Or if you prefer it in one-line :)

```
$("#termsy_master").clone().attr("id", "his").show().appendTo(".article-content").children("h2").text("new title").siblings(".sm").attr("id", "sm_new_id").siblings(".di").attr("id", "di_new_id");​
```